# The 'npm start' command of my program is not connecting with the localhost of Mongod, which looks to be working wrong

Tags: javascript, mongodb, npm-start

I'm working on a prototype program that registers accounts, and I'm doing so using Node.JS to program in JavaScript so I can apply it on mobile.

I got MongoDB downloaded and created the data/db directory to accommodate it since I'm using its 4.0.2 version for me to be able to use it on Windows 8.1. And I try to use the `mongod` command in the command prompt to have the local server up with `npm`, but as far as I can understand, mongo is not working properly. It prints out the following when I try to run it:

```
C:\Users\user>mongod
2021-08-03T17:40:37.119-0300 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0,
 to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2021-08-03T17:40:38.707-0300 W  ASIO     [main] No TransportLayer configured dur
ing NetworkInterface startup
2021-08-03T17:40:38.710-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=
3624 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 64-bit host=user-pc
2021-08-03T17:40:38.710-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/
Windows Server 2008 R2
2021-08-03T17:40:38.711-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.15
2021-08-03T17:40:38.711-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: d7fd78dead
621a539c20791a93abec34bb1be385
2021-08-03T17:40:38.711-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2021-08-03T17:40:38.711-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2021-08-03T17:40:38.711-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2021-08-03T17:40:38.712-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2012plus
2021-08-03T17:40:38.712-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2021-08-03T17:40:38.712-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64

2021-08-03T17:40:38.712-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2021-08-03T17:40:38.716-0300 W  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdo
wn - C:\data\db\mongod.lock is not empty.
2021-08-03T17:40:38.719-0300 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in
C:\data\db\ created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active st
orage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2021-08-03T17:40:38.721-0300 W  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Recovering data from th
e last clean checkpoint.
2021-08-03T17:40:38.722-0300 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config:
 create,cache_size=1087M,cache_overflow=(file_max=0M),session_max=33000,eviction
=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=
true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=
100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),
verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress],
2021-08-03T17:40:39.026-0300 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [162
8023239:25693][3624:140728932634752], txn-recover: Recovering log 18 through 19
2021-08-03T17:40:39.377-0300 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [162
8023239:377270][3624:140728932634752], txn-recover: Recovering log 19 through 19

2021-08-03T17:40:39.819-0300 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [162
8023239:819672][3624:140728932634752], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting
 at 18/256 to 19/256
2021-08-03T17:40:39.827-0300 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [162
8023239:826508][3624:140728932634752], txn-recover: Recovering log 18 through 19

2021-08-03T17:40:40.324-0300 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [162
8023240:324574][3624:140728932634752], file:index-3--5844570482911569703.wt, txn
-recover: Recovering log 19 through 19
2021-08-03T17:40:40.644-0300 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [162
8023240:643927][3624:140728932634752], file:index-3--5844570482911569703.wt, txn
-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: (0, 0)
2021-08-03T17:40:41.297-0300 I  RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTime
stamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
2021-08-03T17:40:41.308-0300 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] No table logging settin
gs modifications are required for existing WiredTiger tables. Logging enabled? 1

2021-08-03T17:40:41.316-0300 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Timestamp monitor start
ing
2021-08-03T17:40:41.411-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2021-08-03T17:40:41.413-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access cont
rol is not enabled for the database.
2021-08-03T17:40:41.417-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and wr
ite access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2021-08-03T17:40:41.418-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2021-08-03T17:40:41.419-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server
 is bound to localhost.
2021-08-03T17:40:41.420-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote syst
ems will be unable to connect to this server.
2021-08-03T17:40:41.422-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the s
erver with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP
2021-08-03T17:40:41.425-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses i
t should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
2021-08-03T17:40:41.426-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all
 interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
2021-08-03T17:40:41.428-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with
 --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
2021-08-03T17:40:41.433-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2021-08-03T17:40:41.441-0300 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection loca
l.system.replset as collection version: <unsharded>
2021-08-03T17:40:41.452-0300 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Flow Control is enabled
 on this deployment.
2021-08-03T17:40:41.454-0300 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection admi
n.system.roles as collection version: <unsharded>
2021-08-03T17:40:41.457-0300 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection admi
n.system.version as collection version: <unsharded>
2021-08-03T17:40:41.462-0300 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection loca
l.startup_log as collection version: <unsharded>
2021-08-03T17:40:41.935-0300 W  FTDC     [initandlisten] Failed to initialize Pe
rformance Counters for FTDC: WindowsPdhError: PdhExpandCounterPathW failed with
'O objeto especificado não foi encontrado no computador.' for counter '\Memory\A
vailable Bytes'
2021-08-03T17:40:41.937-0300 I  FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time
diagnostic data capture with directory 'C:/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2021-08-03T17:40:41.946-0300 I  SHARDING [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] Marking co
llection config.system.sessions as collection version: <unsharded>
2021-08-03T17:40:41.949-0300 I  SHARDING [LogicalSessionCacheReap] Marking colle
ction config.transactions as collection version: <unsharded>
2021-08-03T17:40:41.951-0300 I  NETWORK  [listener] Listening on 127.0.0.1
2021-08-03T17:40:41.952-0300 I  NETWORK  [listener] waiting for connections on p
ort 27017
2021-08-03T17:40:42.108-0300 I  FTDC     [ftdc] Unclean full-time diagnostic dat
a capture shutdown detected, found interim file, some metrics may have been lost
. OK
2021-08-03T17:40:42.126-0300 I  SHARDING [ftdc] Marking collection local.oplog.r
s as collection version: <unsharded>
```

How do I make it work properly?

Comment: Seems fine? Did you try connecting to the DB with a client?

Comment: i'm trying to run an app using node.js, i typed the 'npm start' command on the command prompt, and it does not work. Well, i'll check if i made mistakes on the algorithm, since it seem the Mongod is working properly...
The main reason i believe the problem lies with Mongod, is because the VS's command prompt says, among many other lines: "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Authentication failed.". but it also says "This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch()". So i'll check

Comment: That suggests you're not entering the username/password correctly? They should be included in your URI. Are you following a tutorial similar to this one? https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-nodejs-mongodb--how-to-get-connected-to-your-database

Comment: the tutorial i'm following is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M49dO1PRuUQ

Answer (score 1):

Your MongoDB instance is working fine, check the lines below:

```
2021-08-03T17:40:41.951-0300 I  NETWORK  [listener] Listening on 127.0.0.1
2021-08-03T17:40:41.952-0300 I  NETWORK  [listener] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

That means that Mongo is OK. In the other hand, your error say:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Authentication failed.
```

That explain to you that you are putting your credentials wrong (username and password), and apart from that, you are not catching the errors while trying to connect to mongo (with a **try/catch** block) so you got **UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning**

**npm start** is the default npm script to run your application, and it has nothing in common with your MongoDB instance.

My recommendation is to download Robo3T (or another client) and check first if you can connect to your MongoDB instance from there. Once you achieve that, you can keep testing the connection from Node.js

Hope it helps to clarify :)